# Cannot find the type of ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, datasource, connection-pooling

[image: Image of ComboPooledDataSource class not being found]

When I try to write a database connection pool, it cannot find the type of `ComboPooledDataSource`. Why is this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have c3p0 jar in classpath & you have imported `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` in your class.